# Format XML file

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following xml file:

```
        <table name="countries">
            <column name="id">1</column>
            <column name="name">Abkhazia</column>
            <column name="code">XZ</column>
            <column name="phone_code">+995</column>
            <column name="flag">xz.gif</column>
        </table>
```

how can i format this xml to something like this?

```
        <countries>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>Abkhazia</name>
            <code>XZ</code>
            <phone_code>+995</phone_code>
            <flag>xz.gif</flag>
        </countries>
```

is there some online resources for this?

Comment: basically nothing, i tried to find some online resources that can format XML files, but i didn't found anything that would help me, maybe you know some resources that might help me, the only way in which I stopped is - manually change all xml

Comment: XSLT is the best choice for this. Since there is no standard way of "reformatting" you need to write specific instructions (in XSLT)

Comment: If it will be always like this then you can use regular expressions, and simple replace function, if you want to write code that will do this, very simple script.

Comment: So you didn't search for how to convert between XML formats?

Comment: Or use some xml parser that is available for your language of choice if your xml will be more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This short and simple transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{@name}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<table name="countries">
    <column name="id">1</column>
    <column name="name">Abkhazia</column>
    <column name="code">XZ</column>
    <column name="phone_code">+995</column>
    <column name="flag">xz.gif</column>
</table>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<countries>
   <id>1</id>
   <name>Abkhazia</name>
   <code>XZ</code>
   <phone_code>+995</phone_code>
   <flag>xz.gif</flag>
</countries>
```

Comment: @anonymous: You are welcome. Please, consider accepting the best answer in order to help the readers find it quickly.

Answer (score 3):

It is just basic work with xml in any programming language. I've done it in XSLT without programming, transformation which produces desired output (tested here: [XSLT Transformation - Online Toolz](http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php)), mabye there is more elegant way, I'm not expert in XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="table">
<xsl:variable name="tableName" select="@name"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:element name="{$tableName}">
  <xsl:for-each select="column">
     <xsl:variable name="columnName" select="@name"></xsl:variable>
     <xsl:element name="{$columnName}">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
   </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```